# Do source code optimizers exist?

Tags: optimization, compiler-construction

Are there any tools out there which perform source code optimization? I know compilers perform optimization on intermediate representations, but I am interested in seeing how an automated tool might perform source level optimization.

Comment: What is source code optimization supposed to do? Re-write your code for you? Sounds quite dangerous frankly...

Comment: @Nim - Yes, that's exactly what I'm interested in. I'm not saying it is a good solution. I just want to know if anyone has done that sort of thing before.

Comment: @harold: "... if your're going to output a monstrosity..."  I think you are tarring a vast set of technologies with the results of one with which you may have a bad experience.  That's a bad generalization.  You get monstrosities when you program them.  Don't do that.  My personal experience is much, much better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You are interested in [program transformation systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_transformation), which allow you to express optimizations as "source to source" transformations.   People have done a *lot* of this, but these tools are not widely known.

"Sounds quite dangerous..."  All technology is dangerous if misused, and incredibly useful when applied to the right problem.

Comment: I don't know if I would say program transformation systems count in the manner you present them here. He specifically requested source to source and optimizations. I am more than aware that those systems are capable of such, but you did not show that they are being used to do optimizations and returning back with the starting language. In other words, I would expect a better answer from you on this and you would be one who would know. :)

Comment: I am also thinking that proof assistants could fall into this answer as they can take major portions of a proof and reduce it to one line. He didn't limit the answer to common programming languages.

Comment: @GuyCoder:  All the program transformations systems at the Wiki site can transform code, and return a modified program in source form; that's what makes them "program transformation systems".   The point of such tools is to let users define arbitrary transformations (of which "optimizations" are a special but not particularly distinguished case).  As examples of this, the Rose Compiler is used by scientific computing organizations (e.g, LLNL) to optimize supercomputing C++ and FORTRAN programs.  We've used our tool to covert C++ with array operations into C++ with embedded vector instructions.

Comment: ... the motivation for PTS *was* optimization.  The set of program transformation tools doing optimization is surprisingly large if you dig into the research literature, and goes way back to at least the mid 1970s, (e.g., the Irvine Program Catalog, which is where I first encountered this idea: http://www.bayfronttechnologies.com/itc76.pdf‎).    The notion of "optimization" is pretty broad, depending on what you want to optimize.  So, yes, "proof assistants" can fall into this category by optimizing "proofs", which, like programs, are just documents with a formal meaning.

Comment: ... For the last 10-20 years, PTS have found new life in the software reengineering space, for doing langauge migrations (source-to-source, but from one language to a different one) or what I do a lot of, which is large scale code reorganization, which if you like is "optimizing code structures".

Comment: With regards to this question, with noting the Irvine Program Catalog you have rounded out what I was expecting in an answer. You noted the tools but when I work with source code transformations I also need rules to drive the tools and that was missing in the original answer.

Comment: I know you don't have a [CS.StackExchange](http://cs.stackexchange.com/) account but I asked a follow up [question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/18583/268) there because they are more tolerant of questions of a list nature when taged with [reference-request](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-request)

Comment: All the PTS tools mentioned accept explicit transformation rules.